# PHP - Get value of input field and pass it through the link

Tags: php, post, get

I get the id trough the link, this is no problem because there is a table "id" in the database, but i also want to pass the value from input field "quantity" trough the link.. Thank you in advance!

```
 <?php

    require_once 'database.php';


    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '%s'", $id);
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    echo '<table>';
    ?>

    <form action="add.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> ADD quantity </legend>
    Quantity: <br>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" size="15"> </input> </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    ?>
```

Comment: You should use `hidden` input field to pass `id`.

Comment: Do you want ```quantity``` input to have a value? Where is your value?

Comment: @AliFarhoudi value is chosen on the page

Comment: Below will be a guy telling you not to use `mysql_*` functions. Be warned.

Comment: You don't close your while loop, why?

Comment: Hi you should not to use mysql_* functions :)  what Peter didn't mention was why... and the why is that you have SQL injection issues above.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a post request, so you should be able to get it like this :

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
```

Comment: after $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; how can i put this value in a session on the next page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple GET values you can separate them via `&amp;` (`&`).
You can do this:

```
<a href="page.php?id=1&quantity=10">link</a>
```

**Note**: is better (standard) to use `&amp;` instead of `&`. like this:

```
<a href="page.php?id=1&amp;quantity=10">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_POST` var, as it follows:

```
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
```

But please, don't put the $id var and the $quantity directly on the sql query it will lead to mysql-injection attacks. Use PHP's PDO class or sanitized your input with proper function (like `mysqli::real_escape_string()`). And please not that mysql_* functions are deprecated since php 5.5 and removed since php 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use this:

```
 <form action="add.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="GET">
 <fieldset>
    <legend> ADD quantity </legend>
Quantity: <br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="15"> </input> </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And Get data from:

```
$_GET['quantity']
```